# Find out the percentage for each case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE runner_orders (
  "order_id" integer,
  "runner_id" integer,
  "distance" decimal (5,2),
  "duration" decimal (5,2),
  "cancellation" varchar(23)
);

INSERT INTO runner_orders
  ("order_id", "runner_id", "distance", "duration", "cancellation")
VALUES
  (1, 1,  20, 32, ''),
  ('2', '1',  20, 27, ''),
  ('3', '1',  13.4, 20, ''),
  ('4', '2',  23.4, 40, ''),
  ('5', '3',  10, 15, ''),
  ('6', '3',  NULL, NULL, 'Restaurant Cancellation'),
  ('7', '2',  25, 25, ''),
  ('8', '2',  23.4, 15, ''),
  ('9', '2',  NULL, NULL, 'Customer Cancellation'),
  ('10', '1', 10, 10, '');
```

And they ask me:

> What is the successful delivery percentage for each runner?

I did this, that finally gave me the correct results:

```
WITH cte_1
AS (
  SELECT runner_id, (COUNT(runner_id))*100 AS percentages
  FROM runner_orders 
  WHERE cancellation = ''
  group by runner_id
)
SELECT cte_1.runner_id, (percentages/(COUNT(ru.cancellation))) as percentages_successful_deliveries
FROM cte_1
FULL JOIN runner_orders AS ru
  ON cte_1.runner_id = ru.runner_id
GROUP BY cte_1.runner_id, cte_1.percentages
ORDER BY runner_id
```

But I wonder, How can I get the same results in a shorter query? I tried subqueries, and It didn't work for me. This is one of the many subqueries I tried:

```
SELECT runner_id, ((COUNT(runner_id) over (PARTITION BY runner_id, cancellation))*100)/(count(runner_id))
FROM runner_orders
group by runner_id, cancellation
```

So how I can make this work in a shorter and more simple way than a CTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
select runner_id,
       count(case when cancellation = '' then 1 end) *100.0 / count(*) as percantage
from runner_orders
group by runner_id
order by runner_id
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nduZMztZ)

`count(case when cancellation = '' then 1 end)` means, for each `runner_id` count only the rows where `cancellation = ''`. The case expression inside the count will return null for rows where `cancellation <> ''` and 1 (you may use anything other than 1) for other rows, noting that the count function is not counting null values, this will return only the count of rows where `cancellation = ''`.

Comment: omg I want to cry of how simple that is haha thank you! I did try using CASE but I did something like (count(runner_id) case when cancellation = '' then 0 end)) something like that and of course it didn't work haha

Comment: Added extra explanation for how conditional count works, hope this will help you.

Comment: yes Im reading it and taking notes, good explanation,  thank you! is not hte first time I see a CASE with column = '' then 1, but I still struggle to get it and use it correctly haha Well, Im just in my second month learning SQL. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. It will be a simple matter for you, all you need is some practice to get familiar with the syntax.

Comment: Or `count(duration) * 100.0 / count(*)`

Comment: @Charlieface, nice catch, I just noticed that the duration is null when the delivery is canceled.